# PHP Sessions, Roles and IF statements

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I have a question about which one is better? any feedback?

```
<?php

if (htmlentities($_SESSION['user_role'], ENT_QUOTES) != 'R') {

}

?>
```

OR

```
<?php

if ($_SESSION['user_role'] != 'R') {

}

?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please? Which is better for what?

Comment: Do you need htmlentities ? If no, go in simple way.

Comment: the bottom one is better. what justification do you have for considering the top one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `htmlentities` is to change things to valid HTML.  All you care about here is whether the thing in `$_SESSION` is 'R,' and changing it to valid HTML won't alter that (as 'R,' like any other ASCII character, is already valid HTML).

Since there's no need for `htmlentities`, skip it.